# How to dynamically add to PHPExcel spreadsheet

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpexcel

Alright, So I have this code

```
        $key = $_SESSION['order_nums'];
        $sqll = "SELECT * FROM `money` WHERE `order` = :key";
        $qq=$con->prepare($sqll);
        $qq->bindvalue(":key", $key);
        $qq->execute();


        $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $excel2 = $excel2->load('nTest.xlsx'); // Empty Sheet
        $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $worksheet = $excel2->getActiveSheet();

        while($fdata=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {   
            $worksheet
                ->setCellValue('A7', $fdata['code']);


        }
```

Where it it setting the cell value for A7 there is about 6 more of those that match. When I do it like this however, It only puts its into the CELL A7

```
            while($fdata=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {   
            $worksheet
                ->setCellValue('A7', $fdata['code']);


        }
```

How can I make it where
The above value will Drop down one cell for each new entry.

So the next would be A8, A9..... and so on.

Comment: the cell address is just a string. `setCellvalue('A' . $row, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `'A7'` isn't some kind of magic value, it's just a normal PHP string that's passed as a standard function argument to the `setCellValue()` method.... you can replace it with a string variable that you define yourself, and change for each row

```
    $column = 'A';
    $row = 7;
    while($fdata=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {   
        $worksheet
            ->setCellValue($column . $row, $fdata['code']);
        $row++;

    }
```

Comment: He is not leaving it @Pamblam In my question I asked to start at A7, He is simply writing it how I requested.

Comment: meh i removed the downvote, i realize that's how he had i just think he might be confused and doesn't really mean to start out on the 7th..

Comment: I am the author. I am not confused at all. I am intending to start on the 7th @Pamblam

Comment: @Kmiles1990123 - Got it, my apologies. Please hit the check by Mark's answer if he helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row = 'A';
while($fdata=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    $col = 1;
    foreach($fdata as $data){
        $worksheet->setCellValue("$row$col", $data);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}
```

Comment: Damn you, I was typing my own answer xD You got here first though xD